# Proof that $\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty } n\sum\limits _{j=2}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{j-1}}{j^2} \left( 1-{j}^{-1} \right)^{n-1}} = -\frac12$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients, riemann-zeta, binomial-theorem

> How can we prove the following?
>
> $-1+\frac1{12}{\pi }^{2}-\frac12\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty }\Gamma  \left( n+1 \right) \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+2}
> \,{\frac {\zeta  \left( k \right)   \left( -
> 1 \right) ^{-2+k} \left( {2}^{2-k}-2 \right) }{\Gamma  \left( -1+k
>  \right)  \left( n+1-k \right) !}} =\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }n
>  \sum\limits_{j=2}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{j-1}}{{j}^{
> 2}} \left( 1-{j}^{-1} \right) ^{n-1}} =-\frac12$

We also have
$\chi(n)=-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+2}\zeta  \left( k
 \right)  \left( k-n-2 \right) {n\choose k-2} \left(  \left( -1
 \right) ^{1+k}{2}^{1-k}+ \left( -1 \right) ^{k} \right) $ by replacing the $\Gamma$ factors with the corresponding binomial occeficient

Related question at [References for $ \chi(n)=n\sum\limits_{j=2}^\infty\frac {(-1)^{j-1}}{j^2}\left(1-j^{-1}\right)^{n-1}$ in $\zeta$ expansion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2851837/references-for-chin-sum-j-2-infty-frac-left-1-right-j-1#2851837)

> Digits := 37; flist(proc (n) options operator, arrow; evalf(coolchi(n)) end proc, 0 .. 75);
>                           Digits := 37
> [                                              
> [0., -0.1775329665758867817637924166769874055, 
>
>   -0.158151287891164991627192075621149797, 
>
>   -0.100756475454096876860689273411921431, 
>
>   -0.052729122560581908477394880842614692, 
>
>   -0.022173447806981260740844120495648785, 
>
>   -0.005724758139923986695354623118140584, 
>
>   0.001711181525440404872086057781767772, 
>
>   0.004163504754435619487164038876686477, 
>
>   0.004224146796392587120306729731994248, 
>
>   0.003361436685455899377754627000698078, 
>
>   0.00231507684250186191279422185478205, 
>
>   0.00140312527387483007618661260684936, 
>
>   0.00072272177218128957979732200349640, 
>
>   0.00026840905319980399461855630763639, 
>
>   -0.00000386786514313326830151239928860, 
>
>   -0.00014529652172375174501064342971419, 
>
>   -0.00020079200685610596363763783920190, 
>
>   -0.00020486397550091241285507339640177, 
>
>   -0.00018177251376674866978557090651028, 
>
>   -0.00014732720568299891079533324844990, 
>
>   -0.00011103259250611536839455447354313, 
>
>   -0.00007801852557445637063802766476294, 
>
>   -0.00005057002459089850935720449502326, 
>
>   -0.00002924737982070438622370684257219, 
>
>   -0.0000136577182218588710540784871811, 
>
>   -0.0000029575122625340335255970335431, 
>
>   0.0000038395199899767419714034429197, 
>
>   0.0000076881193734840299247444522077, 
>
>   0.0000094245398419219327153653943207, 
>
>   0.0000097337529690318816412614692587, 
>
>   0.0000091480274459270312096627770217, 
>
>   0.0000080619145517535381759258176097, 
>
>   0.0000067542476407336638941225910227, 
>
>   0.000005411593443449269790648097261, 
>
>   0.000004150125437131325581547336324, 
>
>   0.000003034497471576312110001308212, 
>
>   0.000002093267538135562252003012925, 
>
>   0.000001330969825279401198332450463, 
>
>                                  -7  
>   7.37209507955248062779620826 10  , 
>
>                                  -7  
>   2.93263622398134958434524015 10  , 
>
>                                  -8  
>   -2.3317072362848976102839973 10  , 
>
>                                   -7  
>   -2.35650675570634484892471134 10  , 
>
>                                   -7  
>   -3.65620346716670870284369471 10  , 
>
>                                   -7  
>   -4.32803484845776951918534983 10  , 
>
>                                   -7  
>   -4.53980382773092409894967670 10  , 
>
>                                   -7  
>   -4.43028271969806636513667532 10  , 
>
>                                   -7  
>   -4.11056601063391173974634568 10  , 
>
>                                   -7  
>   -3.66679744724574133777868780 10  , 
>
>                                   -7  
>   -3.16354929829636515323370167 10  , 
>
>                                   -7  
>   -2.64737199886948816611138728 10  , 
>
>                                   -7  
>   -2.15021028592691266141174466 10  , 
>
>                                   -7  
>   -1.69250991341964200913477377 10  , 
>
>                                   -7  
>   -1.28592821342563655928047463 10  , 
>
>                                  -8  
>   -9.3562155186891501184884726 10  , 
>
>                                  -8  
>   -6.4212079021714840683989162 10  , 
>
>                                  -8  
>   -4.0282829593958497425360774 10  , 
>
>                                  -8  
>   -2.1318155241615525408999560 10  , 
>
>                                 -9  
>   -6.753256088468931634905523 10  , 
>
>                                -9  
>   4.020837075521115896921341 10  , 
>
>                                 -8  
>   1.1611930078301706186481030 10  , 
>
>                                 -8  
>   1.6596359914684719233773543 10  , 
>
>                                 -8  
>   1.9500255425207775038798882 10  , 
>
>                                 -8  
>   2.0789463805547333601557044 10  , 
>
>                                 -8  
>   2.0865770984321044922048033 10  , 
>
>                                 -8  
>   2.0067518073257429000271847 10  , 
>
>                                 -8  
>   1.8673131375018625836228485 10  , 
>
>                                 -8  
>   1.6906432963871255429917949 10  , 
>
>                                 -8  
>   1.4942881292166557781340237 10  , 
>
>                                 -8  
>   1.2916159703946332890495351 10  , 
>
>                                 -8  
>   1.0924629207316840757383290 10  , 
>
>                                -9  
>   9.037454965393441382004053 10  , 
>
>                                -9  
>   7.300036840122634764357642 10  , 
>
>                                -9  
>   5.739399681529520904444054 10  , 
>
>                                -9                               -9
>   4.367571268906899802263293 10  , 3.185931532251771457815357 10  
>
>   ]
>   ]

> listsum((20))=    -0.4999999932944069400650356605249833795

Note: when evaluating this sum, at appears at least 28 digits of precision are required for accurate evaluation. If you use less than this (Maple defaults to 10) then the result will diverge quite wildly to an inaccurate answer.

This table is the partial sums of the terms, so I think the equality =-1/2 is correct

> [0., -.1775329665758867817637924166769874055, -.3356842544670517733909844922981372025, -.4364407299211486502516737657100586335, -.4891698524817305587290686465526733255, -.5113433002887118194699127670483221105, -.5170680584286358061652673901664626945, -.5153568769031954012931813323846949225, -.5111933721487597818060172935080084455, -.5069692253523671946857105637760141975, -.5036077886669112953079559367753161195, -.5012927118244094333951617149205340695, -.4998895865505346033189751023136847095, -.4991668647783533137391777803101883095, -.4988984557251535097445592240025519195, -.4989023235902966430128607364018405195, -.4990476201120203947578713798315547095, -.4992484121188765007215090176707566095, -.4994532760943774131343640910671583795, -.4996350486081441618041496619736686595, -.4997823758138271607149449952221185595, -.4998934084063332760833395496956616895, -.4999714269319077324539775773604246295, -.5000219969564986309633347818554478895, -.5000512443363193353495584886980200795, -.5000649020545411942206125671852011795, -.5000678595668037282541381642187442795, -.5000640200468137515121667607758245795, -.5000563319274402674822420163236168795, -.5000469073875983455495266509292961795, -.5000371736346293136678853894600374795, -.5000280256071833866366757266830157795, -.5000199636926316330984998008654060795, -.5000132094449908994346056782743833795, -.5000077978515474501648150301771223795, -.5000036477261103188392334828407983795, -.5000006132286387425271234815325863795, -.4999985199611006069648714785196613795, -.4999971889912753275636731460691983795, -.4999964517817673723156103664483723795, -.4999961585181449741806519319243573795, -.4999961818352173370296280347643303795, -.4999964174858929076641129272354643795, -.4999967831062396243349832116049353795, -.4999972159097244701119351301399183795, -.4999976698901072432043450251075883795, -.4999981129183792130109815387751203795, -.4999985239749802764021555134096883795, -.4999988906547250009762892912784683795, -.4999992070096548306128046146486353795, -.4999994717468547175616212257873633795, -.4999996867678833102528873669618293795, -.4999998560188746522170882804392063795, -.4999999846116959947807442084866693795, -.5000000781738511816722453933713953795, -.5000001423859302033870860773605573795, -.5000001826687597973455835027213313795, -.5000002039869150389611089117208913795, -.5000002107401711274300405466264143795, -.5000002067193340519089246497050733795, -.5000001951074039736072184632240433795, -.5000001785110440589224992294505003795, -.5000001590107886337147241906516183795, -.5000001382213248281673905890945743795, -.5000001173555538438463456670465413795, -.5000000972880357705889166667746943795, -.5000000786149043955702908305462093795, -.5000000617084714316990354006282603795, -.5000000467655901395324776192880233795, -.5000000338494304355861447287926723795, -.5000000229248012282693039714093823795, -.5000000138873462628758625894053293795, -.5000000065873094227532278250476873795, -.5000000008479097412237069206036333795, -.4999999964803384723168071183403403795, -.4999999932944069400650356605249833795]

Comment: Are you sure the last equality is true?

Comment: I get $\pi^2/8$.

Comment: Not sure numerically is trustable, but I get $-0.632...$ this way if I cut the series at $N=500$. Dunno if that is sufficient.
Looking at the series however you can see that the sum over $n$ is just the derivative of the geometric series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$ with respect to $x$ evaluated at $x=1-1/j$. So you can carry out that summation and you'll get $$\sum_{j=2}^\infty (-1)^{j-1} = -1/2 \, .$$

Comment: A confirmation about the numeric evaluation being so slow would be nice though.

Comment: the evaluation of the infinite sum is tremendously slow, but the finite sum zeta polynomial is very fast if you have a lookup table of values of zeta at the integers

Comment: @RonGordon with which calculator?

Comment: @Diger neat, but I'm not sure I follow the reason why that is allowed, can you please elaborate?

Comment: To be honest: I don't really know! I guess this is quite delicate as for when you would replace $(-1)^{j-1}$ by $1^{j-1}=1$ then the entire result diverges. Also the last sum with alternating $1$s and $-1$s is not really defined, but only in the sense of analytic continuation.
Therefore I guess your sum above would have to be replaced by some function
$$
f(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
 \left( \sum _{j=2}^{\infty }{\frac { x^{j-1}n}{{j}^{
2}} \left( 1-{j}^{-1} \right) ^{n-1}} \right)
$$
with $|x|<1$, because then the series is absolutely and uniformly convergent and can you interchange

Comment: summation order. Then $f(x)$ is evaluated at $-1$ which amounts for, if your sum is the result of meromorphic function represented by this series, then the value of this function can be attached to it.

Comment: @Diger interesting, I am quite sure it really converges to -1/2, when I took out the evaluation using 37 digits of precision to 200 terms, it diverged, but when I set precision to 50 digits, it converged to -1/2 as expected.

Comment: Mathematica code:`Sum[Sum[((-1)^(j - 1)*n)/j^2*(1 - j^-1)^(n - 1), {n, 1, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> j > 1] // Simplify, {j, 2, Infinity}, 
 Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]` gives: $-1/2$

Comment: @crow Do you want a proof of the single identity in the title or of the double idendity below the title? Plus, what have you tried for proving them?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco the double identity as well, the title length limit prevented putting it in the title . not much so far, I just noticed it empirically when doing some computer assisted algebra , that's why I am asking here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following assume $|z|<1$ to begin with and I'll let $z \to 1$ to get the OP's left hand side formula:
$$ S(z):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n\,n \sum_{j=2}^\infty\, \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j^2}\big(1-\frac{1}{j}\big)^{n-1} .$$
$S(z)$ is solvable in closed-form in the following manner:  Interchange summations and to eliminate the $n$ series use the derivative of the geometric series to obtain

$$S(z)= z\sum_{j=2}^\infty\, \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j^2(1-z(1-1/j))^2}=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}\sum_{j=2}^\infty\, \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{ (j+z/(1-z))^2 }.$$
This sum is solvable in the terms of the trigamma function, once a $j=1$ term is added and subtracted.  Thus

$$S(z)= \frac{z/4}{(1-z)^2}\Big( \psi\,'\big(\tfrac{3}{2}+\tfrac{z}{2(1-z)}\big) - \psi\,' \big( 1+\tfrac{z}{2(1-z)} \big) \Big) .$$

To find the limit $z \to 1,$ it is seen that it is equivalent to

$$S(1) = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{1}{4y^2} \Big( \psi\,'\big(\tfrac{3}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2y}) - \psi\,' \big(1+\tfrac{1}{2y} \big) \Big)  =
 \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{4} \Big( \psi\,'\big(\tfrac{3}{2}+\tfrac{x}{2}\big) - \psi\,' \big( 1+\tfrac{x}{2} \big) \Big)$$
$$= \lim_{x \to \infty}  \frac{x^2}{4} \Big(\frac{2}{x}-\frac{4}{x^2}+\mathit{O}(x^{-3}) - (\frac{2}{x}-\frac{2}{x^2}+{\mathit{O}}(x^{-3})) \Big)= -\frac{1}{2}$$
where the asymptotic formula for the trigamma function has been used.

Comment: Why is the interchange of a limit and a summation, licit?

Comment: @skbmoore that's a pretty cool formula. I see that the series expansion of S has the n-th term in the expansion being $\chi(n)$

Comment: @Did.  Assume z is 'small enough.'  Do the sum and the final result tells us that there are no singularities until $|z|=1.$  Abel's theorem, I believe, lets us take the limit.

Comment: ?? "You think"? The reason that make you sure the step is legit should be written down explicitely in your answer.

Comment: @Did the referenced paper says the two series are absolutely convergent so the interchange is legit

Comment: @crow Are you saying that the paper says that the double series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \sum_{j=2}^\infty\, \frac{1}{j^2}\big(1-\frac{1}{j}\big)^{n-1}$$ converges?

Comment: @Dig maybe.. see section 2 , page 6 thru 9 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.1440.pdf "The validity of switching the two summations in Eq. (27) and the limit existence of m →∞
are ensured by absolute convergence of the two series"

Comment: @crow 1. Using wrong usernames after @ is a good way to make them unnoticed. 2. Why do you avoid answering my simple query by sending me back to a paper on arXiv? 3. How is (27) in the paper you link to, related to the double series here? 4. Again, *do you think the double series in my comment converges?* 5. If your way of justifying the interchange of sums is that it does, you might want to look closer at the matter (and by that, I mean, to look at it yourself, not to refer to some random page in some random paper).

Comment: I don't care enough to do so

Comment: @crow Ooookaaaay... Well then say so from the beginning, for example by including a mention to this effect in your question. (Still not ready to use @ correctly, are we?)

Comment: @Did I dont get paid to do this, my head hurts, my back hurts, its Sunday, im broke and trying to find ways to survive, responding to nitpicking on the internet isnt fun. Do you really think the interchange is disallowed? It gives the right answer, it is an exponential generating function for the elements $\chi(n)$ so really it can't be wrong

Comment: @crow "so really it can't be wrong" And there goes mathematics in the modern sense... (But kudos for, finally, using @.)

Comment: @Did the paper linked to is not random, its the paper which defined the series in question, and you are not the arbiter of what is and isn't mathematics, what is modern? Just a useless adjective... kind of like "cloud computing". just obfuscation. If you think the interchange is not allowed, prove it. Are you a journal editor or something?

Comment: @crow "Are you a journal editor or something?" It happens I am, but what does this have to do with whether the double series converges absolutely or not, whether you can be bothered to check it, whether the reference you gave helps or not, and all the strange points of view you seem to be advocating?

Comment: @Did I find your "point of view" also strange, so we are even. good questions, when I submitted my last paper to a journal I wondered why the editor refused to look at any other content in my paper because I dared to include "standard definitions that all experts already knew" in my paper.  rather than tell me what was logically wrong with any of the deductions  or any actual logical mistakes I made. just trying to understand the mindset. I'll check the convergence of the series

Comment: @crow My point of view on all this is simply to wonder "Why [you think that] the interchange of a limit and a summation, [is] licit?" Yes, this was already my first comment but, thanks to your peculiar attitude, it seems we have made zero progress on this. Your choice, I guess.

Comment: @Did if we apply the ratio test to the summand ${\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{j-1} n }{{j}^{2}} \left( 1
-{j}^{-1} \right) ^{n-1}}$ the absolute value of the ratio is $ \left| {\frac { \left( n+1 \right)  \left( j-1 \right) }{j \left( n
 \right) }} \right| $ which has the limit $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } \left| {\frac { \left( n+1 \right) 
 \left( j-1 \right) }{j \left( n \right) }} \right| ={\frac { \left| j
-1 \right| }{ \left| j \right| }}$ which is $\le 1$ for finite $j$ and approaches $1$ from below as $j$ tends to $\infty$

Comment: the ratio is $ \left| {\frac {n+1}{n} \left( 1-{j}^{-1} \right) ^{n} \left(  \left( 
1-{j}^{-1} \right) ^{n-1} \right) ^{-1}} \right| = \left| {\frac {
 \left( n+1 \right)  \left( j-1 \right) }{j  n }}
 \right| $

Comment: So, each inner series converges, right (and by much simpler arguments). *But this is not the problem at all*...

Comment: @Did  please enlighten us

Answer (score 4):

Write $\chi(n) = n \sum _{j=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j^2} \left( 1-\frac{1}{j} \right)^{n-1}$ using OP's notation. Its partial sum up to the $(N+1)$-th term can be simplified by interchanging the order of summation:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \chi(n)
&= \sum _{j=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j^2} \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} n \left( 1-\frac{1}{j} \right)^{n-1} \\
&= \sum_{j=2}^{\infty} (-1)^j \underbrace{ \left[ \left(1 + \frac{N+1}{j}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{j}\right)^{N+1} - 1 \right] }_{=: f_N(j)},
\tag{1}
\end{align*}

Since $f_N(j) = \mathcal{O}(j^{-2})$ as $j\to\infty$ for each fixed $N$, $\text{(1)}$ is indeed a convergent series. Now grouping successive terms, $\text{(1)}$ simplifies to

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \chi(n)
&= - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (f_N(2k+1) - f_N(2k)) \\
&= - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{2k}^{2k+1} f_N'(x) \, dx  \\
&= - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (N+1)(N+2) \int_{2k}^{2k+1} \frac{\left(1 - \frac{1}{x}\right)^N}{x^3} \, dx  \\
&= - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(N+1)(N+2)}{N^2} \int_{\frac{2k}{N}}^{\frac{2k+1}{N}} \frac{\left(1 - \frac{1}{Nu}\right)^N}{u^3} \, du \tag{$x=Nu$}
\end{align*}

Then Fubini-Tonelli's theorem gives

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \chi(n)
= - \frac{(N+1)(N+2)}{N^2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(1 - \frac{1}{Nu}\right)^N}{u^3} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left[\frac{2k}{N}, \frac{2k+1}{N}\right]}(u) \right) \, du.
$$

Since the integrand is bounded by the integrable dominating function $e^{-1/u}/u^3$, as $N\to\infty$ we have

$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \chi(n)
= - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-1/u}}{u^3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \, du
= - \frac{1}{2}.
$$